# What is the norm of the gradient of $f$ in normal coordinate?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $f$ a smooth function on $M$. The Bochner formula proved in Schoen-Yau's book "lectures in Differential Geometry": (prop. 2.2)
$$
\Delta |\nabla f|^2(p)=2\sum _{ij} |f_{ij}|^2 +2 R_{ij}f_i f_j +2 \sum f_i(\Delta f)_i
$$
The proof assumes that ${x_i}$ are normal coordinates around $p$. and $f_i$ is the co variant differential of $f$ with respect to $\partial/\partial x_i$. $R_{ij}$ is the Ricci tensor.

Then the proof proceed as follows: Since $|\nabla f|^2=\sum f_i^2$. Hence at $p$ one has
$$
\Delta |\nabla f|^2 =\sum_j(\sum f_i^2)_{jj}=.....
$$

My question is actually the first claim $$|\nabla f|^2=\sum f_i^2$$
It seems for my that in general $$\nabla f=f_sg^{si}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$
In normal coordinate we can only get the expression $|\nabla f|^2=\sum f_i^2$ only holds at the point $p$, not other points. But clearly we need to take derivative, the value at the point $p$ is not enough.

It's most likely I miss some point here, but I can't figure out why. Anyone can help?

Comment: By definition of Levi-Civita connection, the covariant derivative of the metric tensor vanishes.

Comment: @achillehui how does that help?

Comment: The $f_{ij}$ there are covariant derivatives of $f_i$. When you use Levi-Civita connection, the partial derivatives of $g^{st}$ in $\partial_j( g^{st}f_s f_t)$ will be stuffed into the $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ part of $f_{ij} = \partial_j f_i - \Gamma_{ji}^k f_k$. You no longer need to worry about the partial derivatives of $g_{st}$ explicitly.

Comment: @achillehui I don't understand your answer. It seems that you agree with that $|\nabla f|^2 =g^{st}f_sf_t$ not $f_i^2$. My question is which one is THE expression of $|\nabla f|^2$?

Comment: $|\nabla f|^2 = g^{st}f_sf_t$ in general. But at $p$, $g^{st} = g_{st} = \delta_{st}$ and the 'value' of $|\nabla f|^2$ reduces to $f_i^2$. Since we have used co-variant derivatives for bookkeeping the partial derivatives from $g^{st}$ and we only need numbers over a single point $p$, there is no need to explicitly include $g^{st}$ in the expression.

Comment: @achillehui Let me rephrase your explanation to make sure I understand you correctly. If we let $h=|\nabla f|^2$ then the notation $h_{ii}$ means $(\nabla dh) (\partial x_i, \partial x_i)$. So what you meant is that for $h=g^{st}f_s f_t$ and $h'=f_i^2$ we have $h_{ii}(p)=h'_{ii}(p)$?

Comment: If your $\nabla$ stands for co-variant derivative, then yes. Since the co-variant derivatives of metric tensor vanishes, you can lower/raise indices, contract two indices and taking co-variant derivative in any order you like.

Comment: If you $\nabla$ stands for the Levi-Civita connection, then yes too. It is the co-ordinate free way to say exactly the same thing.

Comment: @achillehui At the point $p$ we have $$h_{ii}(p)=\nabla_{\partial x_i} \nabla_{\partial x_i} (h)|_p = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (g^{st}f_s f_t)|_p-\Gamma_{ii}^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}(h)|_0$$ The second term in the last equation is zero since we choose normal coordinate at $p$. SO you mean $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (g^{st}f_s f_t)= g^{st} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (f_s f_t)|_p= \sum_s f_s^2$$

Comment: The $2^{nd} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ in the $2^{nd}$ term of $2^{nd}$ line should be a co-variant derivative. Even though it is equal to a partial derivative numerically at $p$. further differentiation of it will pickup the 2nd derivatives of $g_{st}$. This is basically how you get the Ricci tensor at the end. Since the system is complaining our comments is too long and obviously I can't help you. Let's call this a stop.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, the point that *achille hui* was trying to make is that you can commute tracing with respect to the metric $g$ and covariant derivatives. In other words, you can take the terms $g^{ij}$ out of the covariant derivatives.

In general, you have $\left|\nabla f\right|^2=g^{ij}f_if_j$. Then,

$$\Delta\left(\left|\nabla f\right|^2\right)=tr_g\nabla^2\left(\left|\nabla f\right|^2\right)=g^{kl}\nabla^2_{k,l}(g^{ij}f_if_j)=g^{kl}g^{ij}\nabla^2_{k,l}(f_if_j).$$

So if you are working in geodesic normal coordinates centered at $p$, the RHS corresponds to the term $\sum\limits_j\left(\sum\limits_if_i^2\right)_{jj}$ in your question.